Fixing memory leaks in R when Valgrind does not point at my code
What can I do when valgrind doesn't say something of the form "memory leak in src/the_file.cpp" (and sometimes it adds "line 10")?
Here I do a simple std error computation with a code that I am working on (https://github.com/pachadotdev/fixest2/blob/cpp1124/dev/se.R):
library(fixest2)

lhs = 'y1'
rhs = 'x3'
all_rhs = c('', 'x2', 'x3')
n_rhs = 1
k = 1

base = readRDS("dev/base.rds")

# try to create a memory leak by repetition
for (i in 1:10) {
  est_multi <- feols(c(y1, y2) ~ x1 + csw0(x2, x3) + x4 | species + fe2, base, fsplit = ~species)
}
# ok

# try to create a memory leak by repetition
for (i in 1:10) {
  mat <- coeftable(object = est_multi[[1]],
      vcov = NULL, ssc = NULL, cluster = "fe3",
      keep = NULL, drop = NULL, order = NULL)

  mat[, 2]
}
# problem

But Valgrind just points at R internals and not at lines in my code, as it was the case with older memory leaks that I fixed. It shows (https://github.com/pachadotdev/fixest2/blob/cpp1124/dev/se.txt):
...
==52939==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==52939==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==52939==    by 0x49F0E14: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
...

I am running R with memory debugging in this way:
R --vanilla -d 'valgrind -s --track-origins=yes'


Two possible issues. 1. You have not enabled debug symbols. 2. You are using outdated valgrind.

I compiled with PKG_CPPFLAGS += -UDEBUG -g. I will try to update Valgrind.
